# Logic App - Azure blob storage - Extract to archive folder action - RequestEntityTooLarge

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I am trying the [Azure blob storage - Extract to archive folder action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#Extract_archive_to_folder) for [Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/).

I have a file in my blob storage (more than 50MB) and I've created a logic app (HttpTrigger) that just executes this action:

[image: Logic App - Azure blob storage - Extract to archive folder action]

After triggering the logic app, the action failed with this error:

[image: Logic App - Azure blob storage - Extract to archive folder action - RequestEntityTooLarge]

> RequestEntityTooLarge: The file contains 52.225 megabytes which exceeds the maximum 50 megabytes.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked with the internal product team regarding this matter, the limit can't go over zipped files over 50Mb. (I asked to have public documentation to be updated so everyone can know this).

**Suggestions:**
You can either split the zip files and keep them under 50MB **OR** upload the files as uncompressed files(Limit for that is 1Gb per file)

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've ended up using an Azure Function for this particular action but good suggestion. In my scenario.